# Reflecting within a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, reflection

Here is a little Javascript code snippet where I have used a function to simulate an object. I tried to reflect upon the member functions (which are really nested functions of the function) , but somehow the code does not work.

Can someone please help me understand why the code does not work. I am trying to understand the underlying principles of Javascript which cause this code to not work.

Thanks.

```
var test = function () {

    var first = function first () {
        alert ("first");
    }

    var second = function second () {
        alert ("second");
    }

};

function getOwnFunctions(obj) {
    for(var f in obj) {
        if(typeof(f) == "function" && obj.hasOwnProperty(f)) {
           alert(f);
        }
    }
}

getOwnFunctions(test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple points here:

1. `var` defines the scope of the variable, which is saying that the
   `first` & `second` functions are
   only available inside the `test`
   function. To simulate a `object`,
   you want to use the `this` keyword.
2. `for(var f in obj)`: the `for` loops
   over the object and returns the
   **keys** in `obj`, so  `typeof(f)` will always return the type of the
   `f` **variable** which will be a
   `string`, you want to check for
   `typeof(obj[f]])` which will return
   the type of the actual underlying
   property.
3. You want to call `getOwnFunctions`
   with a instance of `test`, not the
   actual `test` function:

.

```
var test = function () {    
    this.first = function() {
        alert ("first");
    }    
    this.second = function() {
        alert ("second");
    }    
};    
function getOwnFunctions(obj) {
    for(var f in obj) {
        if(typeof(obj[f]) == "function" && obj.hasOwnProperty(f)) {
           alert(f);
        }
    }
}

getOwnFunctions(new test);
```

Comment: @parag Works for me in firebug, what browser are you using? try `new test()`

Comment: @"The Scrum Master" I tried it on Chrome (5.0.375.99 beta on Linux) and Firefox 3.5.9 using this code snippet on JSFIddle http://jsfiddle.net/adaptives/QZWgV/

Comment: @parag Interesting, works for me in FF, IE, chrome & safari. http://jsfiddle.net/YaudC/

Comment: @parag You are missing my first & second point. You need to check for `typeof(obj[f])` **not** `typeof(f)`, also remove the `var` and use `this`. Read my answer again.

Comment: @"The Scrum Master" Just to clarify one more thing. You mention "type of the f variable which will be a string". I am not sure I totally understand that. Is it because keys of Javascript objects are Strings?

Comment: @parag While iterating over the property names of a object, the key is a just the property name as a `string`, to get the actual property, you need to use `obj[key]`.

Comment: @"The Scrum Master" Thanks, your explanation has been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The `var` keyword introduces a symbol that's local to the dynamic scope of the function call, not the contextual scope of the `this` referent.

Comment: I tried removing the 'var' keyword from the nested functions, but no success with that too.

Comment: Instead of that, use `this.foo = "bar"` to define properties of the context object.

Answer (score 1):

So if you want a function to have "methods" you would treat the function like an object:

```
var test = function () {};

test.first = function first () {
  alert ("first");
}

test.second = function second () {
  alert ("second");
}

function getOwnFunctions(obj) {
  for(var f in obj) {
    if(typeof(f) == "function" && obj.hasOwnProperty(f)) {
      alert(f);
    }
  }
}

getOwnFunctions(test);
```

The great thing here is you can do things like the following:

```
function x(y){
  alert( y );
}

x.test = function(){this('test');}

x.test();
```

alerts test